# Failed running JAR file in Ubuntu crontab

Tags: ubuntu, jar, cron

I am trying to run a JAR file as crontab task. For some reason it doesn't execute the file at all. Thus, there isn't any output in the log file. All I can see when running:
`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` is the attached image.

The cron tab is configured as follows:

```
*/60 * * * * /home/medisafelog/sudo java -jar UniqueUsersCounter.JAR > /home/medisafelog/cron.log
```

[image]
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the arguments for the moment, the command you are issuing appears to be:

```
/home/medisafelog/sudo
```

Is that really a command in your environment?

Comment: no, i need to run the JAR file named UniqueUseresCounter. when i run it from the terminal i use " sudo " before the command in order to run it with sufficient permissions

Comment: Ok. i got it to work. changed it /usr/bin/java -jat /home/... xx.JAR

Answer (score 1):

Is this your crontab, or a system-wide one? If it's system-wide, then it needs the username of the user that's running the program. If it's your own crontab... what's the "/home/mediasafelog/sudo" doing? It looks like that's the program you're trying to run, with "java" as the first argument.

If so, and if this is a copy of sudo, then all sorts of things might go wrong. You normally can't have setuid programs under /home. Put it in as a system-wide script if it needs to be run as root.

If that's a red herring, and you're not trying to run it under sudo, then it might well be a path thing. The PATH you have set when you're at the terminal might well not be the same as the PATH that's in force when the cron job gets run. (It uses a fairly vanilla PATH to make sure there aren't security problems with running the wrong program.) You could try putting

```
which java
```

or

```
echo $PATH
```

into the crontab to see what's going on.

Comment: THanks, im knida new to Linux so im not sure i followed all the way. im using "crontab -e" to edit the crontab so i guess it is mine crontab (?). i need to run the JAR with sudo permissions caus it updating files when it runs and i put in the crontab the exact same command i use in the terminal. what would you suggest?

Comment: Ok. i got it to work. changed it /usr/bin/java -jat /home/... xx.JAR